# Sublime Text regex to isolate an achor tag

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm looking for a Sublime Text regular expression that will enable me to find and replace all anchors within an HTML file.

For example:

```
<a href="#Menu">menu</a>) the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)">
```

I've tried this but it finds *all* links and anchors – I just want anchors:

```
(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)</a>
```

I've also tried this but it selects two nearby a tags and everything in between:

```
(<a href="#)(.*)("{1})>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the eventual solution I came up with:

```
(<a href="#)([^"]+)("{1})>
```

This allows me to replace anchors like so:

```
$1" onclick="alert('yay')">
```